# Cassandra get_range_slice

Tags: c#, java, c++, python, cassandra

When get_range_slice returns, in what order are the columns returned? Is it random or the order in which the columns were created? Is it best practice to iterate through all resulting columns for each row and compare the column name prior to using the value or can one just index into the returning array?

Comment: What does this question have to do with C#, Java or C++?

Comment: These are probably programming language of thrift library he is using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The columns for each row will be returned in sorted order, sorted by the column key, depending on you comparator_type.  The row ordering will depend on your partitioner, and if you use the random partitioner, the rows will come back in a 'random' order.

In Cassandra, it is possible for each row to have a different set of columns, so you should really read the column key before using the value.  This will depend on the data you have inserted into you cluster.